# ASP.NET to SQL Server Credentials

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, user-management

I am currently working on converting a Windows Desktop application to a Web Site/Application. The data structure for the entire application is stored in SQL Server databases. Each database represents a different "library". One customer can have many different "libraries" (databases), and I'm contemplating placing many customer installations on the same web server.

This will be an internet site, so I'm strongly considering using Microsoft's supplied user account management for site access. I'm thinking that I would then provide administrator-level access that would allow a user to be assigned privileges on a particular database. (i.e., by default, creating a user account through the Microsoft mechanisms wouldn't give any real functionality.)

User access would have the following generic levels: 
1. Read access (without this, the user shouldn't even know the library exists)
2. Insert access (user can add records to the system)
3. Edit access (user can alter the details of a record)
4. Delete access (what do you think this does :)?)
5. Admin access (user can modify other users' attributes)

I'm considering a model where there is a single account in the website that handles all SQL Server interactions. Thus, all of the code to handle allowing/denying access levels 1 through 5 above would be handled by code in my website pages, rather than by SQL Server's user account management.

I'm thinking that I would have one, central database that would contain all user names and to which libraries their account has (at least) read access (level 1 access from above). Then, levels 2 through 5 would be stored in each database for that user and that database.

Two questions occur to me:

1. Is this approach reasonable? Am I missing another way to do what I want (like, using SQL Server's user management tools) that is safer?
2. If I were going to enact this method, how would I create the "SuperUser" account on the website? I'm assuming it would be some sort of "NETWORK SERVICE" or "LOCAL SERVICE" account, but I'm still a little bit hazy about which account does what in ASP.NET.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you use ASP.Net Login authentication using Roles and Membership.. I think this should help you..

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't make to clear, but I plan to use ASP.NET Forms authentication to control access to the site. My question is more related to the interaction between the site and SQL Server. Is there a good way to use ASP.NET Forms authentication to accomplish this? My question is more about having a central website account to manage the SQL interactions. Is that more clear?